# How to configure workflow_choice in-Gitlab CI

Tags: gitlab, github-actions, gitlab-ci, workflow, cicd

Here I have a syntax in github actions. Now I need to Configure the same in gitlab CI.

```
name: Staging - Parser Service Action
run-name: Staging - Deploy Parser ${{ github.event.inputs.choice }} by @${{ github.actor }}
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      choice:
        type: choice
        description: Choose which parser or service to deploy
        options:
        - workflow1
        - workflow2
        - workflow3
```

Could anyone please help with this? Thanks in advance.